# How to place a loop in this JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a timeout function and I want it to loop from reading. This is what I did. I think I get the idea but not with the syntax:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function flip() {

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.flip').addClass('show2')
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.flip').removeClass('show2')
    }, 2000);
  });
  $(window).load(function() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      flip();
    };
  });
</script>
```

I have a function called flip that adds or removes class in every 1 sec , then I have a function that should run flip function for ten times.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: where is your error? in the for loop?

Comment: Start by looking at errors thrown. You have several but mentioned none. Get those sorted out then you have a logic problem based on the loop to sort out

Comment: `for ( let i = 0; i < 10; i++) { flip(); }`

Comment: Fixed my answer. Added the parameters for the recursive function in the right place.

Comment: You should just use `setInterval` for this. That won't work like you think. Every one of those will overlap asynchronously as you created those timeouts in the loop. You should just test for an HTML class and alternate if it's there or not.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Timeouts don't work this way. Basically what you're telling JS to do is

> Run `$('.flip').addClass('show2')` 1000ms from now
>
> Run `$('.flip').removeClass('show2')` 2000ms from now
>
> Run these events 10 times immediately

So you're setting the timeouts all at once.

You're better off running these with a callback:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    function flip (show, counter) {
        // if max amount of repetitions is reached
        if(counter > 20) return; // return exits the recursive function
        
        $('.flip').toggleClass('show2',show); // Add boolean as parameter for toggle function
        setTimeout(flip, 1000,!show, ++counter); // Call flip using parameters:
                                                  //   (not)show
                                                  //   counter increment
        console.log('Show: ' + show)
    }
    flip(true, 0);
});
```

```css
.flip {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.show2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip">
</div>
```

I'll break down the code for you:

```
function flip (show, counter)
```

We'll declare a `flip` function that receives two parameters: `show` will be a boolean, and it will control wether the `show2` class will be added to the element; and `counter` will control the amount of times that the function will be called.

```
function flip (show, counter)
```

Since `counter` validates the amount of times the function has beed called, once it reaches 20, `return` will exit the function, causing the recursive loop to end.

```
$('.flip').toggleClass('show2',show);
```

The [`.toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) jQuery function replaces the `.addClass` `.removeClass` functions, since it can receive a boolean parameter that will `addClass` when `true` and `removeClass` when `false`.

```
setTimeout(flip, 1000,!show, ++counter)
```

Use the setTimeout function to program the execution of the `flip` function 1000ms from now (in this case, `flip` is called a callback function). Since this is a recursive function, we can use the same parameters received to change the action to be performed by the next function call.

`!show` negates the boolean parameter `show`. It literally means `(not)show`. Since the first time the function is called, the value received is `true`, we'll send `(not)true` to the function call, so it will toggle the `show2` class by removing it.

`++counter` is an [arithmetic increment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment) that adds 1 to the `counter` variable *before* sending it as a parameter. It's the same as sending (counter + 1) as a parameter, so that the next function call receives a +1 increment from the last, up until it reaches 20, when the recursive function calls will stop.

If [sending parameters to the callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) is necessary, they must be sent after the time value, separated by commas.

```
flip(true, 0);
```

This call to the `flip` function starts the recursive loop, and we're sending `show = true` and `counter = 0` as parameters.

Hope it's all easier to understand this way.

Comment: `flip` not in scope where it is being called

Comment: Fixed the example. The parameters for the recursive fallback were misplaced.

Comment: Thank you @Niche but I kind of lost in this script, I know it might obvious to other advanced users, but if you can try to explain it each line in words, so I will learn something from your answer too.
like what is the purpose of -Return- ?
why on the toggle class the is -show- parameter ?
how come the toggleClass is not inside the SetTimeout ?
what is the -!show- and the ++counter ?
what is the -Flip(true, 0)- ?
I know I am asking a lot so I will understand if it is too much to ask

Comment: I updated my answer to further explain how the code works.

Comment: Thank you so much!
one thing I didn't get it why the **toggleClass** line not execute if its before the **setTimeout**

Answer (score 0):

Read my comment, then:

```
$(function(){
function flip(){
  var s = 0;
  var f = setInterval(function(){
    $('.flip').toggleClass('show2'); s++;
    if(s === 20){
      clearInterval(f); f = undefined;
    }
  }, 1000);
}
flip();
});
```